# Swap the words of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to swap words of string in such a way that the first word is swapped with the last word ,the second word with the second last word and so on using plain javascript.
Eg :- "Secret Life is Beautiful Key"
Output :- "Key Beautiful is Life Secret"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
var str = 'Secret Life is Beautiful Key';
var reversed = str.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 4):

Hey the easiest solution would be:

```js
  const str = 'Secret Life is Beautiful Key'

  console.log(str.split(' ').reverse().join(' '))
```